# Understanding promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Let's say I have this 'pseudo'code

```
static async fetchAuthData () {

        AsyncStorage.getItem('authtoken', (err, value) => AuthData.token = value)
            .then( (value) => {

                { ...Ok token fetched... }

            })
            .catch( (err) => { 
                return Promise.reject('Some sort of error');
            });

        AsyncStorage.getItem('userid', (err, value) => AuthData.userid = parseInt(value))
            .then( (value) => {

                { ...Ok userid fetched... }

            })
            .catch( (err) => { 
                return Promise.reject('Some sort of error');
            });

        if (token ok && userid ok ) {
            return Promise.resolve('ok');
        }
        else {
            return Promise.reject('Some sort of error');
        }

}
```

I assume `if (token ok && userid ok )` will not get executed until the previous two promises are resolved or rejected.
Am I right?.
Is there some possibility for `if (token ok && userid ok )` get executed before I even get the token?.

This static method is called at the very beginning of my app and this is where I decide to go directly to the app or navigate to the auth flow.

The documentation doesn't seem to be clear about this.

Comment: It will _definitely_ get executed before you get the token, as you don't `await` your promises. `await` is the only way a function can pause its execution. Do you want to get `authtoken` and `userid` one after another, or in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add await to the `AsyncStorage` functions to pause the execution till promise gets resolved and goes to next line

```
static async fetchAuthData () {

 await AsyncStorage.getItem('authtoken', (err, value) => AuthData.token = value)
        .then( (value) => {

            { ...Ok token fetched... }

        })
        .catch( (err) => { 
            return Promise.reject('Some sort of error');
        });

  await AsyncStorage.getItem('userid',(err, value) => AuthData.userid = parseInt(value))
        .then( (value) => {

            { ...Ok userid fetched... }

        })
        .catch( (err) => { 
            return Promise.reject('Some sort of error');
        });

    if (token ok && userid ok ) {
        return Promise.resolve('ok');
    }
    else {
        return Promise.reject('Some sort of error');
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for taking that long. I had to abandon my project for personal issues for the last month. Now resuming. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

as @Amadan said, It will get executed before you get the token
, you need to wait all the promises until they're resolve

```
    static async fetchAuthData () {  
      try {
          const [authtoken, userid] = await Promise.all([
            () => AsyncStorage.getItem('authtoken'),
            () => AsyncStorage.getItem('userid'),
          ]

          if (token ok && userid ok ) {
            return Promise.resolve('ok');
          }
        } catch(err) {
          // handle exception
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of async and await which makes code to execute in a synchronous way.
Check the below code which does the same.

```
static async fetchAuthData () {
try{
   AuthData.token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authtoken')
   userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userid')
   AuthData.userId = parseInt(userId)
   return true;
}catch(err){
   console.log(err)
   return false
}
}
```

If any errors comes up it will be catched in catch block and return false from here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
static async fetchAuthData() {

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('authtoken', (err, value) => AuthData.token = value)
      .then((value) => {
        resolve('...Ok token fetched...')
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        reject('Some sort of error');
      });
  })

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('userid', (err, value) => AuthData.userid = parseInt(value))
      .then((value) => {
        resolve('...Ok token fetched...')
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        reject('Some sort of error');
      });
  })

  if (token ok && userid ok) {
    return Promise.resolve('ok');
  } else {
    return Promise.reject('Some sort of error');
  }

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and add some explanation for future readers